# variable declaration works sometimes, gets "namespace error" others

Tags: typescript, fabricjs, typescript-typings

I have the following code in my project:

```
1  declare const fabric: any;
2  class XCanvas {
3      public canvas: fabric.Canvas;
4
5      constructor() {
6          this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas();
7      }
8  }
```

I am using the wonderful fabricjs library, but I'm using the latest version, and the @types library is a couple versions out of date. I'm struggling to use it in typescript because it always gives errors, but this is the closest I've gotten.

So, line 6 compiles just fine, no problem. But line 3 is giving me this error:

```
Cannot find namespace 'fabric'.
```

Why is this happening? How can I use it in my project without the typings??

I'm not importing or requiring it because I use a script tag to include it in the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use a member of something you declared as `any` as type information, which doesn't quite work. If `fabric` is `any`, then you can't use `fabric.canvas` as a type annotation. Working code:

```
declare const fabric: any;

class XCanvas {
    public canvas: any; // <--

    constructor() {
        this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas();
    }
}
```